# Como usar value de multiselect no php

Tags: php, ajax

Estou pegando um value de um multiselect e o enviando via ajax:

Supondo que o valor do multiselect seja:

```
["1","2","3"]  // é esse valor que está sendo enviado (value do multiselect)
```

Após resgatar esse valor no arquivo php que recebeu do ajax, como eu poderia dar um explode nesse valor apenas para pegar nos números?

Comment: `foreach` para um array ou isso ai é um string?

Comment: Já testaste `$arr = json_decode('["1","2","3"]');` como queres usar esse numeros? nota que esses numeros são strings...

Comment: Então rray, eu estou usando um multiselect e quando faço: $("#multiselect").val() ele retorna isso para mim. Nesse caso são vários valores selecionados de uma vez e enviados via ajax. Eu gostaria de separar esses valores para usá-lo num foreach

Comment: Sim consegui fazer funcionar aqui, mas como posso pegar isso de acordo com o valor enviado? Porque colocando os valores manualmente lá deu certo, mas os valores serão enviados via ajax. Eu pego esse valor assim:
`$valor = $_POST['valor']`, para depois ter que fazer isso

Comment: testa com `$arr = json_decode($valor);`. Funciona assim? senão o que dá `var_dump($valor);`?

Comment: então, ele deu o erro Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Matriculas\index322.php on line 55 e no var_dump está como null

Comment: Lembre de passar true como segundo argumento de json_decode do contrário ele retorna um objeto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, após fazer uns testes verifiquei que tinha um valor que tava recebendo aspa errada.

O comentário do Sergio ajudou bastante , então

```
$arr = json_decode('["1","2","3"]');
```

é válido. Nesse meu caso, pude pegar o array diretamente do jeito que estava vindo do ajax também

então:

```
$array = $_POST['array'] // recebida via ajax

foreach($array as $valor){
      $query = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ('$valor', '1')"; 
      $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao->abrirConexao(), $query);
    }
```

também funcionou corretamente!

O que vale é testar, quebrar a cabeça, que uma hora acaba conseguindo!

Answer (score 1):

Se essa valor for uma string, faça um replace nos caracteres indesejados e com os válidos faça um explode por virgula isso tranformará a string em um array.

```
<?php

$valor = '"["1","2","3"]"';
$str = str_replace(array('"','[', ']'), '', $valor);
$itens = explode(',', $str);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($itens);
```

Comment: rray, me desculpa cara, o valor certo é o seguinte ["1","2","3"], Sem aquelas aspas duplas envolvendo o valor

Comment: @DiegodeSouzaSilva, o json_decode() é a melhor opção então, como recomendado pelo Sergio

Answer (score 1):

A resposta correta depende de como você enviou os dados via ajax, se foi através do método POST, GET ou PUT... Mas partindo do princípio de que você enviou via POST, os dados recebidos, aparentemente é um array, neste caso, seria algo similar a isso:

```
/**
   'data' é a variável que você
   definiu no método do ajax,
   se vc não definiu, basta
   capturar $dados = $_POST;
**/ 
   $dados = $_POST['data'];

  $numeroUm   = $dados[0];
  $numeroDois = $dados[1];
  $numeroTres = $dados[2];

 echo $numeroUm.'<br>' .
      $numeroDois.'<br>' .
      $numeroTres.'<br>';
      die();
```